# What will be the effect on the d.f of $\chi^2$ distribution

Tags: degrees-of-freedom, chi-squared-distribution

Cochran's Theorem says that

> The conditional distribution of $\chi^2=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$ under $m(<n)$ independent homogeneous linear constraints: $$\begin{align}a_{11}X_1+\cdots\dots +a_{1n}X_n&=0\\\vdots \\a_{m1}X_1+\cdots\dots +a_{mn}X_n&=0\end{align}$$ is $\chi ^2_{n-m}$, provided $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are *i.i.d* $N(0,1)$ variables.

It is clear that if the constraint is linear then the *dergees of freedom*(d.f) diminise.If we consider non-linear (like quadratic or cubic) constraint what will be the effect on the d.f of $\chi^2$ distribution.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Is it the conditional distribution of the squared norm of the $X_i$'s conditional to the constraints ? This does not sound like Cochran's theorem to me (but I may be wrong)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: My teacher called the theorem Cochran's Theorem.I am also not sure about that.But this theorem is true and conditional distribution of $\chi^2$ means distribution of $\chi^2$ with the linear restrictions.

Comment: I ask a question here to understand this point http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38111/standard-normal-distribution-on-a-subspace

Comment: To see how difficult the situation is in general, consider the effect of the *single* nonlinear constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2=1$: it reduces $\chi^2$ to a constant!

Comment: @whuber: your comment is very helpful and it clear my problem.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let $U$ be the $(n-m)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by the linear constraints. Then, with the help of @whuber's answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38111/standard-normal-distribution-on-a-subspace), your claim stems from the fact that the conditional distribution of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ given $(X_1,\dots,X_n) \in U$ is a standard normal distribution on $U$.

However there's no similar result when $U$ is not a vector subspace. In such a case one cannot expect that the squared norm of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ has a chi-squared distribution.

Comment: +1 @StephaneLaurent.  Your answer is well written too.  My edit was merely to change "you claim stems from..." to "your claim stems from...".

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks, just mistyped the keyboard :)

Comment: I mentioned it because I didn't want you to think I did any major editing. In my mind that change is imprtant, but just about everyone could guess what you meant and in those situations I think SE prefers that we don't edit.