# Standard normal distribution on a subspace

Tags: normal-distribution, conditioning

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector space with $\dim(U)=d$. A standard normal distribution on $U$ is the law of a random vector $X=(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ taking values in $U$ and such that the coordinates of $X$ in one ($\iff$ in any) orthonormal basis of $U$ is a random vector made of $d$ independent standard normal distributions ${\cal N}(0, 1)$.

When reading [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38086/what-will-be-the-effect-on-the-d-f-of-chi2-distribution#comment74961_38086) I asked myself the following question. Let $Y=(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$ be a standard normal distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is is true that the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $Y \in U$ is the standard normal distribution on $U$ ?

The squared norm ${\Vert X \Vert}^2$ of $X$ has a chi-square distribution $\chi^2_d$. Thus, if this is true, that would explain @Argha's claim.

Sorry if the LaTeX is mistyped, I don't see the LaTeX rendering :(

**EDIT 01/10/2012:** Ok I see. Write $y=u+v$ the orthogonal decompostion of $y$ in $U\oplus U^\perp$. Then $$\Pr(Y\in \mathrm{d}y \cap Y \in U)=\Pr(P_U Y \in \mathrm{d}u)$$. That shows that $(Y \mid Y \in U) \sim P_U Y$. This is little bit heuristic but morally correct. Finally it is clear from the definition that $P_U Y$ is standard normal on $U$.

Comment: Isn't this terribly obvious when you note that an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ can always be constructed by extending any orthonormal basis for $U$?  (One proof: use Gram-Schmidt on any extension, whether orthonormal or not.) In this basis the PDF is separable and *a fortiori* is standard normal on $U$, QED.

Comment: @whuber Please could you elaborate in an answer ? How do you derive the conditional distribution ?

Comment: You just *look* at it! When an absolutely continuous PDF $f(x,y)$ factors as $f_x(x)f_y(y)$, then (a) $X$ and $Y$ are independent and (b) [$f_x$ and $f_y$ are the conditional distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Continuous_distributions).

Comment: @whuber I'm just coming back from work. I will think about this later. Thanks. Of course I believe this is obvious but I'm tired.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You have that $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. Let $Y \sim \text{N}(0,I)$ and $P$ be the orthogonal projection matrix on $U$, so that $P$ is symmetric and idempotent. Then $PY \sim \text{N}(P0,PIP^T) = \text{N}(0,P)$. This is a singular normal distribution, which on the subspace $U$ is the standard normal on that subspace. As a singular distribution, it does not have a density with respect to volume measure in $\mathbb R^n$, but it does have a density with respect to the (lower-dim) volume measure on $U$.

Comment: I don't see where do you prove that $PY$ has the same law as $Y$ conditional to $Y \in U$ ?

Comment: Note that abstractly, conditional probability (really expectation, to get a linear space ...) is a projection! So conditioning on $Y \in U$, when $U$ is a linear subspace, is the same as projecting on $U$.

Comment: Sorry but your claim has no sense.

Comment: That is the intuition, a proof maybe must be different. I am out of time now, but note that the multivariate normal distribution can be specified by specifying the (normal) distribution of all linear combinations of the components of $Y$. When the covariance matrix is the projection $P$, choose $u_1, \dots, u_k$ as an orthonormal basis of $U$. $P$ can be written $P=\sum u_i u_i^T $. Choose as coefficient for the linear combination on of the $u_i$, you will see the variance is one. Choose for the coefficient an length-one vector orthogonal to $U$, you will see the variance is zero.

Comment: So the distribution of $P Y$ coincides with the standard normal in $U$, which is the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $Y \in U$.

Comment: So : 1) You agree that your first comment is wrong / has no sense because you don't evoke the normality in this comment. 2) I agree that $PY$ has the standard normal distribution on $U$ but you still turn around: you claim that this is the conditional distribution, whereas this is the claim to be proved !

Comment: sorry, I will try to come back to this, but I am out of time nw.

Comment: Thanks for your help but please do not feel obliged to answer. This is not a difficult question; I asked this question because I am busy too, but I will find the answer as soon as I have time enough.

Comment: Ok kjeti, I better understand your contribution. You was assuming the fact I have just written in my edit is obvious, and you were right. Then you focused on the fact that $P_U Y$ is standard normal on $U$. But this latter point was clear for me, that's why I misunderstood a little your contribution.